# Switching from object mode to sculpt mode hides one part of my model

Tags: modeling, objects, sculpting

FIXED

I'm still somewhat new to blender but I've managed to almost complete my first model without any problems. Now however out of nowhere this one stupid piece of armour lets me mess around with it in object mode but whenever i try to change mode it just disappears. Like ill be on sculpt mode and it will be there but the second i press alt q on it it vanishes. [image]

- Object Mode

[image]

Sculpt Mode

On the object list it shows the symbol of the mode im in next to it
[image]

I've tried copy and pasting the object to fix it as well as restarting blender. This could be a really easy fix but I'm not sure as I've never encountered this problem. Any help would be much appreciated ! <3

Never mind. All I had to do was change the poly count and it magically reappeared. Hope this helps someone else

Comment: Please do not simply write "FIXED" into the question. This site is aiming to provide sustainable answers for future users with similar problems. Without an existing accepted answer in the answer's section this question might seem unsolved to people looking for a solution. If the answer below solved your problem, you might consider accepting it. If you want to write your own answer providing detailed information on how you solved your problem, you can do this and accept your own answer. If you don't want to provide help for others with the same problem, you might as well delete your question.

Answer (score 1):

you probably accidentally pressed H in either edit mode or sculpt mode, which hides the selection. You can press Alt H to unhide your model or unhide it in the toolbar

[image]